# Data Template for custom panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have created a custom circular panel  inherited from panel class in WPF.

This custom control will arrange all its elements in a circular fashion. Now i want to supply the style for its child elements where ever this control is used.

As below mentioned is the usage of my control and i want to supply child items template to it from here as a property some thing like:   `DataTemplateToUse="{StaticResource ChildItemsTemplate}"`

and this control should be intelligent enough to apply the template to all its children elemnts.

```
<myControl:CirclePanel InnerRadius="250" OuterRadius="300">

</myControl:CirclePanel>
```

ok i have used it as follows

```
<Grid Margin="10">
        <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <local:CirclePanel  x:Name="CircularPanel" InnerRadius="250" OuterRadius="300" Background="Cornsilk" >
                    </local:CirclePanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Title}" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

And dynamically from code behind i am removing the elements from my circle panel so now its throwing the error:

**Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used asItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `ItemsControl` with your panel as `ItemsPanel`. You get all the properties for data templating and binding items.